# Upgrade ruby projects from 1.8.6 to 1.8.7

Tags: ruby

What steps should I follow to upgrade a Ruby project from 1.8.6 to 1.8.7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be mostly seamless, since it was mostly compatible changes to the api.

Still, check out the [list of incompatibilities](http://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_8_7/NEWS#LC426)

If you start using the new methods offered by 1.8.7 (or newer!) but would like to remain compatible with 1.8.6, checkout my [backports gem](http://github.com/marcandre/backports).

Answer (score 3):

There are just method add in ruby 1.8.7 in compare to ruby 1.8.6. So if it's works with 1.8.6 it's works in ruby 1.8.7 too.

But if you are a great test suite, launch it and see if all works.

Answer (score 1):

It's a point release. You shouldn't have to do anything.

Comment: Famous last words.  http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_8_7/NEWS and search on "Compatibility issues".  The Date.parse change is pretty epic in potential confusion.

Answer (score 1):

hey, read this http://casperfabricius.com/site/2010/01/24/multiple-ruby-versions-with-rvm/

it takes you through the installation and setup of Ruby Version Manager - which makes it really easy to switch between different versions of ruby in linux (and mac I think) - if you are on windows, then use this, it's called pik http://github.com/vertiginous/pik/