# How to run code with enumerator in Ruby 1.8?

Tags: ruby, enumerator, ruby-1.8

I have code like this

```
my_enum = [1,2].to_enum
puts my_emum.next
```

and it doesn't work

I understand that the enumerator is available in Ruby 1.8 as an extension. How to install it?(I'm new to ruby)

Comment: Is the typo present in your actual code?

Comment: Karl has got it. There is a typo on line 2 (my_enum, not my_emum).  Enumerator is built in to ruby, this code will work.

Comment: lol, I did not see that typo, thats what happens when you just copy some code and try to run it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755036/why-does-6-times-map-work-in-ruby-1-8-7-but-not-1-8-6/2755067#2755067) to a different question, in Ruby 1.8.6, you can do

```
require 'enumerator'
6.enum_for(:times).map {...}
```

But I don't know if it'll allow you to do `my_enum.next`.

I think the documentation is at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/enumerator/rdoc/ , but it seems to be down right now.

Answer (score 2):

If I fix the typo it works fine. irb session follows.

```
>> my_enum = [1,2].to_enum
=> #<Enumerable::Enumerator:0xb79dd700>
>> puts my_enum.next
1
>> puts my_enum.next
2
```

Tested in

```
>> VERSION
=> "1.8.7"
```

Answer (score 2):

What version of ruby 1.8 are you running? This matters significantly.

(Also note that you have a typo in "my_emum").

In [Ruby 1.8.6](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.6/libdoc/enumerator/rdoc/classes/Enumerable/Enumerator.html) , there is no "next" method for enums, just "each".
Example:

```
my_enum = [1,2].to_enum
my_enum.each do |e|
  puts e
end
```

In [Ruby 1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/generator/rdoc/classes/Enumerable/Enumerator.html), "next" is supported.