# Difference between Ruby 1.8.6 and 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What are the main reasons or pros/cons somebody would choose to work in 1.8.6 over 1.8.7 or vice versa?

So far I can only find this answer, which is from the latest version of the Agile Rails beta e-book:

"Rails 3.0 requires requires Ruby version 1.8.7 or Ruby 1.9.2-preview3. (It is known not to work on Ruby versions 1.8.6, Ruby 1.9.1 and preview releases of Ruby 1.9.2 prior to preview3.)"

But my question is not limited to Rails. For example, http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ still offers 1.8.6 so presumably there are developers who still need that version over 1.8.7.

Comment: I believe this has been covered in [Upgrade ruby projects from 1.8.6 to 1.8.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544185/upgrade-ruby-projects-from-1-8-6-to-1-8-7)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2008/05/31/ruby-1-8-7-has-been-released/

> The new version of Ruby includes many
>   bug fixes, lots of feature
>   enhancements backported from 1.9 and
>   some performance improvements since
>   1.8.6 while maintaining stability and backward compatibility with the
>   previous release to a high degree. See
>   the bundled documentation for details
>   about compatibility issues.

it seems that the improvements are worthwhile to include, especially since web frameworks have to worry about security a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The [1.8.7 ChangeLog](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_8_7/ChangeLog) has a list of *all* the changes in 1.8.7, if none of those changes are important to you then I suppose you could stay on 1.8.6...